# I have a parser to make, i'd like to learn proper parsing

Tags: javascript, parsing, markup, concept

I want to parse text with javascript. The syntax i want to parse is a markup language. this language has 2 main kind of markup:

```
$f56
```

mean the following characters will be of color `#F56`. Until the following `$` with 3 hex char it is using this color.

```
$i
```

Mean until the following `$z` (closing tag) the text is in italic. They are other one letter 
tags.

So basically this language is composed of 3 character long hexa tags for color and one letter long tags.

I can craft something ugly to parse my text, storing char position and current status of tags (formatting and color) but i'd like to learn proper parsing. Could you give me a few tips/principle to make a clean parser for this language ?

Comment: Parsing is fascinating, and it involves ideas derived from the core of computing science. It's a big subject.

Answer (score 2):

If you know about [antlr](http://www.antlr.org) you might be intrested in exploring http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/ANTLR3JavaScriptTarget , which generates javascript lexers and parsers

If you set target language as JavaScript

grammer T.g

```
grammar T;
options {
    language=JavaScript;
    [other options]
}
...
...
```

parser.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/antlr3-all-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="TLexer.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="TParser.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="TWalker.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var input = "...what you want to feed into the parser...",
     cstream = new org.antlr.runtime.ANTLRStringStream(input),
     lexer = new TLexer(cstream),
     tstream = new org.antlr.runtime.CommonTokenStream(lexer),
     parser = new TParser(tstream),
     r = parser.entry_rule();

var nodes = new org.antlr.runtime.tree.CommonTreeNodeStream(r.getTree());
nodes.setTokenStream(tstream);
var walker = new TWalker(nodes);
walker.tree_entry_rule();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

*JavaScript: The Good Parts* has some nice sample code of a simple parser: http://oreilly.com/javascript/excerpts/javascript-good-parts/json.html . That example increments one character at a time, keeping track of this index, but you can also increment by the length of say a matching regular expression result ahead of the cursor.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to learn about parsing, pick up this book: [Compilers: Principles, Techniques, and Tools](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321486811) aka The Dragon book.  It is very dense, but offers the most complete take on parsing.

I've heard good things about ANTLR (mentioned above) but have not used it.  I have used [Bison](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/) though, which worked pretty well for me to define the grammar.